# How to submit form using ajax and normal POST in same time?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I've form that submit data to external URL and the same time I want to save in my database. I've tried `ajax` submit and try to sumbit normal `POST` in ajax success.

Here my code:

```
<form action="http://www.blabla/post" method="post" id="myfrom">
.....
....
</form>

<script>

 $('#myfrom').submit(function() {
  e.preventDefault();
     $.ajax({
              url: 'admin-ajax.php', 
              type: 'POST', 
              dataType: 'html', 
              data: $('#myfrom').serialize(), 
              success: function() {
                   $('#myfrom').submit();
              },
              error: function(e) {
                  console.log(e);
              }
          }); 
  });
</script>
```

But here Ajax is not working form will submit  normal post only.

Comment: what do you get in console.log? and did you print the data you get in your php page?

Comment: a normal post is a whole new page request.  You have to prevent submit from executing before making the ajax call.

Comment: try return false..instead of  e.preventDefault(); and make sure you don't have any errors

Comment: tried `return false`instead of `e.preventDefault();` but now ajax request going in infinite loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
   $('#postData').click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $.ajax({
              url: 'admin-ajax.php', 
              type: 'POST', 
              dataType: 'html', 
              data: $('#myfrom').serialize(), 
              success: function() {
                   $('#myfrom').submit();
              },
              error: function(e) {
                  console.log(e);
              }
        }); 
    });
</script> 

<form action="http://www.blabla/post" method="post" id="myfrom">
<input type="button" value="post" id="postData">
</form>
```

you try this one. make a button  in place of submit button.

Answer (score 5):

change this:

```
$('#myfrom').submit(function() {
```

to this:

```
$('#myfrom').submit(function(e) {
```

---

You have not passed the event in the argument so form gets submitted.

---

This is another way as i see:

```
$('yourButton').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // stops the buttons behavior
    $.ajax({
         url: 'admin-ajax.php', 
         type: 'POST', 
         dataType: 'html', 
         data: $('#myfrom').serialize(), 
         success: function() {
             $('#myfrom').submit(); // submits the form if success
         },
         error: function(e) {
             console.log(e);
         }
    });
});
```

Comment: i was adding this also in my answer but now will not

Comment: @EhsanSajjad oh i see, i just noted in time i think. :)

Comment: yes and also the main reason of adding that is i mostly do return false to stop form submit and stop event's default behaviour.:)

Comment: @EhsanSajjad i think you know `return false;` does two things `e.preventDefault() && e.stopPropagation()` simultaneously.

Comment: so it is fine or not??

Comment: Thanks for answers, but now ajax request going in infinite loop. normal post not work.

Comment: submit data to external server and internal DB

Comment: email subscription database

Comment: You can put another ajax function inside success handler of ajax.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and let you know.

Comment: @miuranga wait i just added another way do this on click of your submit button.

Answer (score 1):

return false after ajax call to stop the normal form submit like this:

```
$('#myfrom').submit(function() {                     
      $.ajax({
              url: 'admin-ajax.php', 
              type: 'POST', 
              dataType: 'html', 
              data: $('#myfrom').serialize(), 
              success: function() {
                    $('#myfrom').submit();
              },
              error: function(e) {
                    console.log(e);
              }
          });
     return false; 
});
```