# How to retrieve the entire state of a component as a single object?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I currently have my getInitialState set up such that the keys and values match up exactly for an AJAX POST call. The state gets completed as the form gets filled, and when the user clicks submit, I'd like for it to just grab the entire state, JSON.stringify it, and then make the post call with that data.

Is that possible? Or do I have to write out some code to map it all out in a new object? If so, what's the quickest way for that that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do indeed have all your data serialized in your component's state, you don't need to do much to access it.  It's available to any method via this.state.  If you're using es6 classes it'd look something like:

```
class MyForm extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        // in es6 Components you need to bind custom methods like this in order to get the this context when called
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // assuming you've been collecting data in state as the user types you can just grab the state
        const data = JSON.stringify(this.state);

        // you'll need an ajax library or you can use fetch
        fetch(someurl, {
          method: 'POST',
          body: data,
        }).then(resp => {
          // handle response
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
              {/* your inputs here */}
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

This is a simple example that handles the form data in an isolated fashion, for a more robust app you may want to use redux and async action creators with thunk middleware.

Comment: oh duh! Thanks so much!

Comment: My pleasure, accessing state is easy, but there's a few gotchas regarding binding the submit handler, hopefully that saves you some time and headaches :-)

Comment: Yeah I had my original code set up in the same format, except i threw in an e.preventDefault()

Answer (score -1):

No need to do anything special. There are multiple ways to submit post using ajax:

```
$("formid").prop("action", '@urlHelper.Action("addrecord", "employee")');
$("#CreateNewSubscriberForm").submit(); // this one in .net
```

Also you can use `[(formid).serialize][1]` to submit the form.

[Here is one answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23933067/how-to-submit-form-using-ajax-and-normal-post-in-same-time) that you can look at. Hope this will help.

Comment: The OP is asking about a react app (see tags) and thus won't be looking for a jquery solution.